# xRDP sound redirection ubuntu 20.04

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, xrdp

I followed the instruction posted in this [tutorial](https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=13655) to install `pulseaudio-module-xrdp`. If I go to the Settings Applet and select sound, then I see xrdp-sink object under sound card. And in the microsoft mstsc.exe client, I enabled sound redirection. I tried both options for client and for remote machine. Both has same result that I don't get any sound. What I want is to play the sound on the remote machine. Is it possible to change the audio driver to headphones on the remote computer?

```
$ sudo aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC887-VD Analog [ALC887-VD Analog]
   Subdevices: 1/1
   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC887-VD Digital [ALC887-VD Digital]
   Subdevices: 1/1
   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
   Subdevices: 1/1
   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

$ aplay -l
aplay: device_list:274: no soundcards found...

$ lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio  Controller (rev 04)
Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 31
Memory at f7d10000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])

$ pulseaudio --version
pulseaudio 13.99.1
```

A test sound is working for sudo:

```
$ sudo aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav
Playing WAVE '/usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Mono
```

For user the sound test fails, also after adding my user to audio group:

```
$ sudo adduser user-name pulse-access
The user `user-name' is already a member of `pulse-access'.
$ sudo addgroup user-name audio 
[sudo] password for user-name: 
Adding user `user-name' to group `audio' ...
Adding user user-name to group audio
Done.
$ aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav
Playing WAVE '/usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Mono
```

If I run `pavumeter` and playback any YouTube video in Firefox. I see "Showing signal levels of xrdp sink" and volume meter moving.

```
$ pavumeter
Gtk-Message: 13:08:58.502: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
** Message: 13:08:58.744: Starting in playback mode.
** Message: 13:08:58.747: Using sample format: float32le 2ch 44100Hz
** Message: 13:08:58.747: Using channel map: front-left,front-right
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an updated script and instruction [blog post](https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=15978). Possibly you just need to run `pulseaudio -k` manually.

Comment: Running `pulseaudio -k` after connecting worked for me. I'm RDC'ing into Ubuntu 20.04 running `xrdp` from Windows 10 Pro, but I haven't tried installing the `pulseaudio-audio-xrdp`  I setup `xrdp` from by following this blog link: https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=15978. Thank You